# How to set retrieve callback in mongoose, in a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to set `db` in global variable, but when I get console `name` out of `findOne` function show me undefined, What can I do?

```
var name;

schema.findone({name : 'Bob'} , function(er , db){
  name = db;
  console.log(db);
});

console.log(name);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Super classic beginner mistake about asynchronism :)

What's going on :

```
var name; // FIRST you declare the name variable

schema.findone({name : 'Bob'} , function(er , db){ // SECOND you launch a request to the DB
  name = db; // FOURTH name is populated.
  console.log(db);
});

console.log(name); // !! THIRD !! you log name - it's empty
```

What you should do :

```
schema.findone({name : 'Bob'} , function(er , db){
  doSomethingElse(db);
});

function doSomethingElse(name){
    console.log(name); // It's defined.
}
```

You souldn't even declare a global variable, as it's a bad practice.
As soon as the data is available, pass it to another function and do something with it. So you don't pollute your global scope.

**Edit** : Since you absolutely want a global variable for some reason, then do this :

```
var name;

schema.findone({name : 'Bob'} , function(er , db){
  name = db;
  console.log(name); // works fine
  doSomethingElse();
});

console.log(name); // name is empty here, because the DB request is still in progress at this stage

function doSomethingElse(){
    console.log(name); // Tadaaaa! It's a global variable and is defined!
}
```

Comment: i want set db in global variable for processing some where else!

Comment: And that's the case. `name` is a global variable, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is Node.JS is asynchronous. You can't set the name globally and console log directly outside the db query callback.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a much cleaner solution. @Throrin that's right, that's what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: it doesn't work, yes it's a global variable and we can use like your code wrote it, but i want use out of the mongoose function, this is a problem,
if you check it out this code you can see what im say! 
I suppose we have to change db e.g. by `JSON.stringify()`, and then do some things more for set in `name` variable.

Comment: @throrin19   do you have any solution, i really need to set this in global, and use it like Json some where else?

Comment: @Hossein you're really stubborn. I did give you the solution, but you don't want to use it. You CAN use your data wherever you want, and I told you how to do it. Throrin won't have any better solution, he will tell you the same thing. You have your data, you can use it everywhere, in any part of your program. That's how it's done. So you can take that solution and understand how Node works, or continue yelling.

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for your answer, i check it out your solution and it worked, but again i don't  wanna use by function, i want set it in global variable
and use it through entire node file like 'export'.

Comment: @JeremyThille i can read 'db' in that function you create it, and i try to set 'db' in some other global variable through that function but i face age 'undefined' errore.

Comment: global vars are the devil

Comment: why devil? :)
i have some experience in php.
in there we can create variables that allow use, use it through our project and all file, they Called 'super global variables'.

do we have like this  'super global variables' in node.js?

Comment: Yeah global variables are bad, in the sense they are "dirty". Variables should be encapsulated in objects, or as in my solution, passed to the funtion that has to use them. I believe you should think about that and make some progress, instead of keep doing what you always do :) But if that's _absolutely_ what you want, set it as a global variable then... I have updated my answer.

Comment: PHP is synchronous, you have no problem with scope vars. In node.JS, it's more complexe and global vars do things which we do not think. In your example, the last console.log is called before the database callback calling because the code is asynchronous. Forgot your PHP base with global vars

Comment: Exactly. PHP is executed line after line, in that order. Forget that with javascript. Everything is asynchronous, and you get your data _when it's ready_, not before. If you try to log it before that, you'll get an error or unexpected result. Javascript does not freeze waiting for data, like PHP. In the meantime, it does something else. That is javascript's power, and what allows Node to be _much_ faster than PHP. So you'd better embrace it :)

Comment: Wow you are actually a douche, is there a way to create global variable which works simply like mongoose.model("model").find(function(err, model){ Model = model;} then console.log(Model) somewhere below this function javascript and node should really be able to know if a variable is in the process of being defined and wait for it....

Comment: Excuse me? Who's a douche?