# Node error cannot set headers after they send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im new to nodeJs and I want to read file from the system,
I was able to see the file content in the console but not in the browser and  I

what am I missing here?

```
var myData = null;
    fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\jbt\\Desktop\\simplefile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("the error is: " + err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        myData = data;
    });
    res.send(myData);
```

I try some other post in SO but nothing helps..

Comment: This question is beginning to be posted too often... always the same answer : Javascript is _asynchronous_. Same question yesterday, please read my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636547/how-to-set-retrieve-callback-in-mongoose-in-a-global-variable/30636635#30636635

Comment: @JeremyThille - Thanks but I dont understand how it helps me here...

Comment: It's just exactly the same problem and the same answer. You're sending a variable that's not been filled because the process is _asynchronous_. It's almost the same code in both questions, except in your case it's readFile instead of a SQL query.

Comment: Aside from the async issues, you're not showing us all of your code, because the code you're showing wouldn't result in the error you're getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to send the response twice ie. res.send() is being called twice that is why once the response is sent you cannot resend it.

Comment: Thanks but not sure that I got it,can you please give an example ?

Comment: Please check how many times in total are you doing the res.send in the api call?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.ReadFile` is async operation, you are sending response back and reading file in parallel. You should do it like this

```
    var myData = null;
    fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\jbt\\Desktop\\simplefile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("the error is: " + err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        myData = data;
        res.send(myData);
    });
```

I would suggest you should read more about Node.js and async method paradigm.

Comment: Thanks but I try to move the  res.send(myData); inside as you did and i got the same error,any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your error if you are getting any ?.Check the below answer.

```
var myData ;
    fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\jbt\\Desktop\\simplefile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("the error is: " + err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        myData = data;
       res.end(myData);//If you are not using express
    });
```

I think it will help you.